# Additive inverses in endomorphism ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I'm working my way through a proof that, given a ring $\langle R, +, \cdot, \theta \rangle$, $\langle \text{End}(R), +, \circ, z \rangle$ is also a ring (where $z(x)=\theta$ for all $x \in R$). Everything seems fine until I try to prove that every element has an additive inverse. For $f \in \text{End}(R)$, I've defined $-f : R \to R$ by the rule $(-f)(x) = -f(x)$ for all $x \in R$. The trouble comes when I try to prove that this function is also an endomorphism, in particular when I try to show that it preserves the product. For $x,y \in R$ I've got $(-f)(x \cdot y) = -f(x \cdot y) = -f(x) \cdot f(y)$ and $(-f)(x) \cdot (-f)(y) = (-f(x)) \cdot (-f(y)) = f(x)f(y)$, so it seems a lot like the product isn't preserved by $-f$. What am I not seeing here?

**Edit**:

This exercise seems more fishy the more I look at it, so I'll include its text here:

> Let $\langle R, +, \cdot, \theta \rangle$ and $\langle R', +', \cdot', \theta' \rangle$ be rings. We denote the set of all morphisms from $R$ to $R'$ by $\text{Mor}(R, R')$. Is $\text{Mor}(R, R')$ closed under the functional addition: $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$? We call a morphism of a ring R into R, itself, an endomorphism and denote $\text{Mor}(R, R)$ with $\mathcal{E}(R)$. Show that $\langle \mathcal{E}(R), +, \circ, z \rangle$ is a ring. (L. E. Sigler *Algebra* Chapter 2 "Rings: Basic Theory" Section 6 "Morphisms" Exercise 11)

I'd also like to point out that, when listing the ring axioms, this textbook forgets to mention the existence of additive inverses (despite stating that requirement later on).

Comment: Perhaps endomorphism here means $R$-module endomorphisms?

Comment: @jgon I don't think so, it's an exercise from an early section of Sigler's Algebra, before linear algebra is even mentioned. It defines an endomorphism as "a morphism of a ring R into R, itself". Though I am curious how your proposition would affect things.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow This textbook distinguishes rings with unity as "unitary rings", and makes no mention of that distinction in this exercise, so that is not required.

Comment: I don't see how $\text{End}(R)$ can be referring to ring endomorphisms here. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $f(x)=x$ (a perfectly fine ring endomorphism). Suppose there is a ring endomorphism $g$ such that $f+g=0$. Then for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $x+g(x)=f(x)+g(x)=0$ so that $g(x)=-x$ for all $x$. In particular, we have $6=-2\cdot-3=g(2)g(3)=g(2\cdot 3)=g(6)=-6$ which is a contradiction...

Comment: For example, the (not-necessarily-unital) ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ are only 0 and the identity: since $1^2 = 1$, you must have $[f(1)]^2 = f(1)$ which implies $f(1) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$.  On the other hand, it is indeed true that the $R$-module endomorphisms of any $R$-module form a ring (and even an $R$-algebra); and in the special case $R = \mathbb{Z}$, that means that the abelian group endomorphisms of any abelian group form a ring.

Comment: Based on these helpful comments I'm beginning to think that the exercise itself is erroneous. For this reason I've included its full text in the original post. It's included too early in the text for the reader to know about $R$-modules.

Comment: If you forget the multiplication and regard the endos as abelian-group-homomorphisms then everything works out.